# How do I use Selenium to automate clicks on multiple links within an iframe?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape data for several bills initiated in the Peruvian Congress from the following website: http://www.congreso.gob.pe/pley-2016-2021

Basically, I want to click on each link in the search results, scrape the relevant information for the bill, return to the search results and then click on the next link for the next bill and repeat the process. Obviously with so many bills over congressional sessions it would be great if I could automate this.

So far I've been able to accomplish everything up until clicking on the next bill. I've been able to use Selenium to initiate a web browser that displays the search results, click on the first link using the xpath embedded in the iframe and then scrape the content with beautifulsoup and then navigate back to the search results. What I'm having trouble with is being able to click on the next bill in the search results because I'm not sure how to iterate over the xpath (or how to iterate over something that would take me to each subsequent bill). I'd like to be able to scrape the information for all of the bills on each page and then be able to navigate to the next page of the search results.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\km13\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://www.congreso.gob.pe/pley-2016-2021")


WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, 'ventana02')))

elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
(By.XPATH, "//a[@href='/Sicr/TraDocEstProc/CLProLey2016.nsf/641842f7e5d631bd052578e20058a231/243a65573d33ecc905258449007d20cc?OpenDocument']")))
elem.click()

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', {'bordercolor' : '#6583A0'})
table_items = table.findAll('font')
table_authors = table.findAll('a')
for item in table_items:
content = item.contents[0]
print(content)
for author in table_authors:
authors = author.contents[0]
print(authors)
driver.back()
```

So far this is the code I have that launches the web browser, clicks on the first link of the search results, scrapes the necessary data, and then returns to the search results.

The following code will navigate to different pages in the search results:

```
elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@onclick,'D32')]/img[contains(@src,'Sicr/TraDocEstProc/CLProLey')]")))
elem.click()
```

I guess my specific problem is being able to figure out how to automate clicking on subsequent bills in the iframe because once I'm able to do that, I'm assuming I could just loop over the bills on each page and then nest that loop within a function that loops over the pages of search results.

UPDATE: Somewhat with the help of the answer below I applied the logic but used beautifulsoup to scrape the href links in the iframe, and store them in a list concatenating the necessary string elements to create a list of xpaths for all of the bills on the page:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\km13\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://www.congreso.gob.pe/pley-2016-2021")


WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, 'ventana02')))

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', {'cellpadding' : '2'})
table_items = table.find_all('a')
for item in table_items:
    elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, "//a[@href='" + item.get('href') + "']")))
    elem.click()
    driver.back()
```

Now my issue is that it will click the link for the first item in the loop and click back to the search results but does not progress to clicking on the next item in the loop (the code just times out). I'm also pretty new to writing loops in Python so I was wondering if there would be a way for me to iterate through the items of xpaths so that I can click an xpath, scrape the info on that page, click back to the search results and then click on the next item in the list?

Comment: `driver.switch_to.frame(number)`

Answer (score -1):

Here is my logic to this problem.

1. First get into the Iframe using switchTo.

2. Get webelements for xpath "//a" using driver.findElements in to a variable "billLinks" as this frame has links for only bills.

3. Now iterate through billLinks and perform desired actions.

I hope this solution helps.

Comment: This sort of helped me get to where I am now although I instead used beautifulsoup to scrape the href links and create xpaths in the loop. Now I'm having trouble getting that loop to click on an item in the loop, click back to the search results and then click on the next item in the loop. See update above.